# Set Attribute value in LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am newbie in LINQ to XML.I have two variable **one** and **two** and I want to set these variable values in attribute in XML.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string one = "first";
        string two = "Second";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(test.xml);

    }
```

XML

```
    <Root>
  <Details XIndex="One" Index="">
    <abc></abc>
  </Details>
  <Details XIndex="Two" Index="">
    <xyz></xyz>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

Now please tell me how I can set One and two variables value in Index attribute in details node.

Example - I want below output.

```
<Root>
  <Details XIndex="One" Index="First">
    <abc></abc>
  </Details>
  <Details XIndex="Two" Index="Second">
    <xyz></xyz>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

Please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`XElement.SetAttributeValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue.aspx) method:

```
var element = doc.Elements("Details")
                 .Single(x=>x.Attribute("XIndex").Value=="One");

element.SetAttributeValue("Index", "First");
```

Comment: var element = doc.Root.Elements("Details");

            foreach (XElement ele in element)
            {
                if (ele.Attribute("XIndex").Value == "One")
                {
                    ele.Attribute("Index").Value = one;
                }
                else if (ele.Attribute("XIndex").Value == "Two")
                {
                    ele.Attribute("Index").Value = two;
                }
            }

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to be making this call often, you might as well put it into a helper method such as:

```
private static void SetValueToDetailElement(XDocument doc, string xIndex, string value)
{
  var detail = doc.Elements("Details").SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Attribute("XIndex").Value==xIndex);
  if(detail != null)
     detail.SetAttributeValue("Index", value);
}
```

and then call the following in your main.

```
SetValueToDetailElement(doc, "One", "First");
SetValueToDetailElement(doc, "Two", "Second");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why answers provided by these guys wont write to XML? There is no exception, everything looks fine except it does not write to file.

Here's mine code

```
string file = "c:/message.xml";
XDocument d = XDocument.Load(file);

SetValueToIdElement(d, id, value);

private static void SetValueToIdElement(XDocument doc, string Id, string value)
        {
            var detail = doc.Elements("context").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == Id);
            if (detail != null)
                detail.SetAttributeValue("value", value);
        }
```

Basically it is same as above